# Why does p5js lag a lot when I use classes?

Tags: javascript, class, p5.js, lag

I'm trying to use classes in `p5js` but when I use `new Object()`, it just lags the website to something like `0.1 FPS`.

```js
let objects = [];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);  
  const object = new Object(width/2, height/2, 50);  
  objects.push(object);
}

function draw() {
  background(20);  
  for (let i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
    objects[i].display();
  }
}

class Object {
  constructor(x, y, r) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.radius = r;
  }
  
  move(x, y) {
    this.x += x;
    this.y += y;
  }
  
  display() {
    noStroke();
    fill(255);
    circle(this.x, this.y, this.radius);
  }
}
```

Does anyone know why this happens and how to fix this? I don't know what else I should try because this is my first time using classes in `p5js`.

Comment: This doesn't work as a [mcve] for me. `Object` can't be the name of a class of yours. It's builtin to JS. Beyond that name clas, making one object shouldn't cause any lag, and doesn't for me. Can you provide a bit more detail? Thanks.

Comment: I tried changing the class name to Circle instead of Object, it actually worked! Thanks a lot ggorlen.

Comment: No problem--probably what's happening is errors are throwing. It's a good idea to look in the console if you weren't already.